# Linter 'pylint' failed to parse the output '. [SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: python, vscode-extensions

I have enabled pylint in vscode but when I run lint, I get very odd error saying output json is not correct.

when I run same cmd in vs code terminal, I get correct json which I validated at https://jsonlint.com/  - so no clue what's going on, anyone can help me with this?

```
2023-06-05 13:45:59.048 [info] > /user/path/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.8.0/pythonFiles/linter.py -p pylint /tools/python/pylint_py3.8.13/2.14.5/rhe7-x86_64/bin/pylint --rcfile pyproject.toml my_python_script.py
```

```
2023-06-05 13:45:59.279 [info] ##########Linting Output - pylint##########2023-06-05 13:45:59.279 [info]2023-06-05 13:45:59.279 [error] Linter 'pylint' failed to parse the output '. [SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON inputat JSON.parse (<anonymous>)at c.parseMessages (/user/path/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.8.0/out/client/extension.js:2:558826)at c.run (/user/path/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.8.0/out/client/extension.js:2:534967)at async c.runLinter (/user/path/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.8.0/out/client/extension.js:2:558341)]
```

here is my vscode setting for linting

```
    "[python]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.python"
    },
    "python.linting.mypyEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.mypyArgs": [
        "--config-file=/mypath/pyproject.toml"
    ],
    "python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,
    "python.linting.flake8Args": [
        "--config=/mypath/tools/infra/lint/flake8.cfg"
    ],
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "--rcfile",
        "/mypath/yproject.toml"
    ],
```

I tried re-installing vscode, running the lint cmd on terminal